# Need to run scripts/commands with root privileges for user selfservices

Tags: linux, bash, root, suid

The core of the topic is a very a common but I am not satisfied.

I have a script looking for a pid and running the `kill` command on the pid if found.

So I `chown` the script to `root.root` and add `4755` as suid.

The script should now run with root privileges, right? Nope.

I stumbled over a nice explanatory article explaining why it ain't working due to security reasons [See Vidar's Blog here](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=30)

Is there a way to achieve the a code like

```
kill -9 3385
```

in the context of root?

Could an approach be to invoke a child script that has the required privileges?

Comment: You can make /bin/kill setuid root and then your system is no longer the same ;-D (protip: don't do it :)

Comment: Anyway I recommend giving sudo right to selected accounts to run the script with root privileges.

Comment: Looks like there is no way around. Cheers mate :)